"Extra \endcsname. Missing \endcsname inserted"error
I am compiling my latex file while I get this error:
[2] [3] (assets/组合计数模型1.tex) [4]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 107--108

[5] [6] [7]) (sections/section2.tex [8] [9] [10]) [11] (gt_main.aux
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.24 ...ne  {E})=1-P(E)\)}{{2.3}{11}{}{cnt.2.3}{}}
                                                  
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.24 ...ne  {E})=1-P(E)\)}{{2.3}{11}{}{cnt.2.3}{}}
                                                  
? 
! Extra \endcsname.
\@newl@bel ...dafter \ifx \csname #1@#2\endcsname 
                                                  \reserved@a \else \@tempsw...
l.24 ...ne  {E})=1-P(E)\)}{{2.3}{11}{}{cnt.2.3}{}}
                                                  
? 
)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `gt_main.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )
Output written on gt_main.pdf (11 pages).
SyncTeX written on gt_main.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on gt_main.log.

And this is my code:
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
%==Math & Physics Packages==
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,theorems}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,theorems}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[nobabel]{highlightx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{diagbox} % 加载宏包
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{zhnumber}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor={black},
    citecolor={skyblue!70!black},
    urlcolor={skyblue!80!black}
}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\mathcolorbox}[2]{\colorbox{#1}{isplaystyle #2$}}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!15}
\newfontfamily{\sectionsfont}{Perpetua Titling MT}
% ==color pannel==
\definecolor{mycyan}{HTML}{03B0B5}
\definecolor{mypeach}{HTML}{FC7970}
\definecolor{myorange}{HTML}{e74c3c}
\definecolor{mystealblue}{HTML}{6591B8}
\definecolor{myteal}{HTML}{169191}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{12CA5E}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{EA2828}
\definecolor{mygrey}{HTML}{969696}
\definecolor{coral}{HTML}{F4564E}
\definecolor{bourguignon}{HTML}{89313E}
\definecolor{skyblue}{HTML}{60BBE5}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{412F66}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{HTML}{B8D28B}
\definecolor{degreen}{HTML}{1d3e17}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{EF9E55}
\definecolor{salmon}{HTML}{F9B3AB}
\definecolor{grape}{HTML}{8C5FBF}
\definecolor{lavender}{HTML}{CBA5E8}
\definecolor{lightpink}{HTML}{FFB6E0}
\definecolor{goldenyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.87, 0.0}
\definecolor{cmr}{RGB}{147,28,23}
\definecolor{bancolor}{RGB}{62,96,111}
\definecolor{teagreen}{rgb}{0.82, 0.94, 0.75}
\definecolor{caribbeangreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.8, 0.6}
\definecolor{coffee}{HTML}{CE9F5E}
\definecolor{rr}{HTML}{F5EAD0}
\definecolor{olivegreen}{HTML}{686B39}
\definecolor{crimson}{rgb}{0.86, 0.08, 0.24}
\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{\thesection}
\newcommand{\yesicon}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[mygreen, line width = 2pt] (-0.075, 0.175) -- (0, 0.05) -- (0.275, 0.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\noicon}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[myred, line width = 2pt] (-0.125, 0.05) -- (0.125, -0.2);
        \draw[myred, line width = 2pt] (0.125, 0.05) -- (-0.125, -0.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\naicon}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[mygrey, line width = 2pt] (0, 0) circle (0.125cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
% =============tcb====================

\def\tcb@theo@widetitle#1#2#3{\hbox to \textwidth{\textsc{\large#1}\normalsize\space#3\hfil(#2)}}
\tcbset{
    theorem style/theorem wide name and number/.code={ \let\tcb@theo@title=\tcb@theo@widetitle},
    proofbox/.style={skin=enhancedmiddle,breakable,parbox=false,boxrule=0mm,
        check odd page, toggle left and right, colframe=black!20!white!92!lightgreen,
        leftrule=8pt, rightrule=0mm, boxsep=0mm,arc=0mm, outer arc=0mm,
        left=3mm,right=3mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm, toptitle=0mm,
        bottomtitle=0mm,colback=gray!3!white!98!skyblue, before skip=8pt, after skip=8pt,
        before={\par\vskip-2pt},after={\par\smallbreak},
    },
}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=cnt, number within=section]{Prop}{Proposition}
    {theorem style=theorem wide name and number,breakable,enhanced,arc=0mm,outer arc=0mm,
        boxrule=0pt,toprule=1pt,leftrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt, rightrule=0pt,left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,
        titlerule=0.5em,toptitle=0.1cm,bottomtitle=-0.1cm,top=0.2cm,
        colframe=white!10!lightgreen,colback=white!90!lightgreen,coltitle=white, coltext=olivegreen!80!brown,
        title style={white!10!lightgreen}, before skip=8pt, after skip=8pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{Prop}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \maketitle
    \vfill
    \tableofcontents
    \vfill
    \newpage
    \input{sections/section1.tex}
    \input{sections/section2.tex}
    
\end{document}

the Section 2.tex is:
\subsection{几个简单命题}
\begin{Prop}{}{
    \(P(\overline{E})=1-P(E)\)}
\end{Prop}

The aux is:
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand*\HyPL@Entry[1]{}
\HyPL@Entry{0<</S/D>>}
\savepicturepage{pgfid1}{1}
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{6171524}{49923808}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}组合计数原理}{2}{section.1}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}基本计数规则}{2}{subsection.1.1}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}分类处理与分步处理}{2}{subsubsection.1.1.1}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2}排列与组合}{3}{subsection.1.2}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}集合的排列与组合}{4}{subsubsection.1.2.1}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}多重集的排列与组合}{5}{subsubsection.1.2.2}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.3}二项式定理与组合恒等式}{6}{subsection.1.3}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.3.1}二项式定理}{6}{subsubsection.1.3.1}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.3.2}组合恒等式}{6}{subsubsection.1.3.2}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.3.3}非降路径问题}{7}{subsubsection.1.3.3}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.4}多项式定理与多项式系数}{8}{subsection.1.4}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.4.1}多项式定理}{8}{subsubsection.1.4.1}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.4.2}多项式系数}{8}{subsubsection.1.4.2}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}概率论公理}{10}{section.2}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1}样本空集和事件}{10}{subsection.2.1}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2}概率论公理}{11}{subsection.2.2}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.3}几个简单命题}{11}{subsection.2.3}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{Prop: \(P(\overline  {E})=1-P(E)\)}{{2.3}{11}{}{cnt.2.3}{}}
\ttl@finishall
\gdef \@abspage@last{11}


Here's the error where I got.

Plz help me to figure out the problem.

Please see this for guidance on preparing a minimal working example to assist people helping you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228. Post errors as text - not images. Independently of that, go through your preamble and remove (1) conflicting packages and (2) packages you aren't using. You cannot use \def\tcb@theo@widetitle# in a document without putting \makeatletter before it. When you've finished, use \makeatother. This switches @ to be a letter so you can use it in command names. The output you show isn't from the code you give (there are only 2 sections).
